# Configuring ActiveMQ to load balance and reconnect

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Using Java how do i configure ActiveMQ to load balance and reconnect when disconnection occur?

As i understand those configuration should be made on the ActiveMQConnectionFactory object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you set the brokerUrl of the ActiveMQConnectionFactory to [a failover transport URI](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html);

```
failover:(tcp://primary:61616,tcp://secondary:61616)
```

If you only have one broker, the below should be enough, ok for testing of reconnects but for production you'll most likely want more than one;

```
failover:(tcp://primary:61616)
```

Unlimited reconnection attempts is the default, but you can tweak quite a few options if you look at the documentation linked above.

Comment: if the remote server reqiures authentication (user and password) where do i supply it? Trying to run activemq with this configuration dont succeed